# GridView. Не все вью полностью помещаются в ячейку

Tags: android, gridview

Заполняю GridView адаптером из LinearLayout с двумя TextView и одним ImageView.
Адаптер:

```
class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data;

        public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videoitem, parent, false);                    
            }
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimestamp)).setText((String)data.get(position).get("timestamp"));

            if (((String)data.get(position).get("imageurls")).equals("")) {
                Picasso
                        .get()
                        .load(R.drawable.standby)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.standby)
                        .error(R.drawable.standby)
                        .into((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView));
            }else{
                Picasso
                        .get()
                        .load((String)data.get(position).get("imageurls"))
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.standby)
                        .error(R.drawable.standby)
                        .into((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView));
            }

            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCameraName)).setText((String)data.get(position).get("cameranames"));


            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/llVideo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundLight"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCameraName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Когда длина текста в каждой из ячеек строки примерно одинакова, то все выглядит отлично. Но если текст по длине сильно различается, то нижняя граница нижнего TextView либо не доходит до границы ячейки, либо наоборот вылезает за границу так, что не виден весь текст.
Мне кажется я уже перепробовал все возможные варианты layout_height как у TextView так и у LinearLayout, но ничего не помогло.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridview не поддерживает разную высоту блоков. Вам нужно использовать recycler view и StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Comment: Как же не поддерживает, если на скриншоте видно, что высота первой строки больше высоты второй? Тут проблема в том, что GridView как-то криво выставляет высоту ячейки, из-за чего большие элементы влезают не полностью. Небольшие же почему-то не занимают все пространство ячейки. У RecyclerView действительно с этим проблем нет, чем я потом и воспользовался.

Comment: Как же не поддерживает, если на скриншоте видно, что высота первой строки больше высоты второй? Тут проблема в том, что GridView как-то криво выставляет высоту ячейки, из-за чего большие элементы влезают не полностью. Небольшие же почему-то не занимают все пространство ячейки. У RecyclerView действительно с этим проблем нет, чем я потом и воспользовался.

Comment: Тот факт что у вас мало текста в первых блоках не значит что сам блок закончился.